# how to move, zoom in or out the layer like coc in cocos2d-x?

Tags: move, cocos2d-x, layer, zooming

I create a level layer which include all the game stuff, such as background, enemies, bullets, player and other decals, I want to make this layer can be moved, zoom in and out,  most likely **clash of clans**, Is there any suggestion or ideal, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your Layer name is **exampleLayer**

**LAYER MOVEMENT**

In your layers **ccTouchMoved** function implement the following code

```
 void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
    {
        CCPoint diff = touch->getDelta();
        CCPoint currentPos = exampleLayer->getPosition();
        exampleLayer->setPosition(ccpAdd(currentPos, diff));
    }
```

**ZOOM IN AND ZOOM OUT**

```
void zoomIn()
{
    exampleLayer->setPosition(-(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width/2),-(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().height/2)); // for positioning the laer in middle
    exampleLayer->setScale(1); // you can set your scale factor 1 is for example
}

void zoomOut()
{
    exampleLayer->setPosition(0,0);
    exampleLayer->setScale(1); // set your desired scale factor
}
```

You can call these methods on your zoomIn and zoomOut button, or as per your game design.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I can move the layer now, but the next thing is bound the layer, to prevent move the background beyond the view port.

Comment: Thanks, I Think the real problem is scroll layer with camera. :-)